# Tool bars and Stored Procedures - Service Reporting (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, report, ssrs-2012

I have two small problems with Reports, I am using SQL Server and SSRS.
I am deploying reports through VS Shell (Report Sever Project).

1. I make a report, do settings, all things ok.
   When I click Preview(VS Shell), the tool bar looks like:

   [image]

   But when I access the report in browser(IE), it looks like:

   [image]

Do you know how I can resolve it?

2. The second problem is about stored procedures. When I open the SSMS (Sql Sever Management Studio) -> Programability -> Stored Procedures,  I see all stored procedures.

   The problem is when I try to use a stored procedure in VS Shell , I don't see them.

   [image]

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

1. Question
   I am not sure but i think this is a IE problem - tried any other browser?
2. Question
   I often used stored procedures as source for reports, but NEVER used Query tpye "Stored Procedure" - didn't work for me. So what you can do is to Change the query type to "Text " and execute your stored procedure here. e.g.

   exec dbo.my_stored_proc

Comment: Hello . IE of Server 2012 R2 has something. Do you know how can I write a select statement to initialise a parameter cause I get an error. I am trying "=select IdAngajat from Angajati where Username=User!UserID", I get an error near ''select'